# how to apply Proxy to scrapy+selenium

Tags: selenium, proxy, scrapy

I got proxy from https://www.zyte.com/ with APIkey and followed their instruction(https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000203564-using-zyte-smart-proxy-manager-with-selenium), but the response time is too long due to it goes through Docker to connect the proxy.

Isn't there any other solution to connect the such proxy to my code? (host url, APIkey and port are given)
I am using Python, Scrapy, Selenium on Window 10